What is the most accurate way to parse a text so that we can get the characters and the list of sentences that refer to each character?
I'm trying to come up with a method that will take a text and parse it so that we can get all the characters and a list of the sentences from the text that have references to the character (either directly by full or partial name or by the pronoun that refers to the character). My current method is to perform coreference resolution to get the clusters chunks of the text, and do this for the entire text in chunks. Next, I perform NER to get the Named Entities, and then retrieve those clusters that contain one of the names from the NER. This isn't giving me great results though. For one, NER will produce different entities for the same character based on full or partial name. For example, David Copperfield would come up as different entities depending on whether he is referred to as "David", "David Copperfield", "Mr. Copperfield", or "Copperfield". What I would want is to parse the book and come up with a Python dictionary that has "David Copperfield" as the key and the list of sentences that contain references to David Copperfield as the value.
Also, I'm using Python, so I'd love to get references for Python packages.

This sort of thing may be on its way to becoming possible with AI, but I still wouldn’t expect it to be at a stage where it’s reliable. Apart from varieties of names (the ones you mention, plus ‘Trot’ and however many more nicknames you can imagine), you’ve got potentially ambiguous uses of pronouns like ‘he’ or ‘who’ – not to mention a fairly infinite number of circumlocutionary noun phrases that might refer to him. ‘The young Suffolk man’, ‘Dora’s widower’, ‘the struggling writer’, etc., would all be reasonable ways to refer to David Copperfield.

Can't you write your algorithm to get: David Copperfield, David, David Copperfield, Mr. Copperfield + Copperfield, then keep the first as key  and the others as values? The point though is that you do have to work through the hits/results of the searches. I see no way around that.

Identify named entities: https://www.nltk.org/ Natural Language Toolkit
